# Start Xubuntu Session in xrdp

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, remote-desktop, aws

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on the my AWS instance and I have installed `xubuntu-desktop` and `xrdp`. After putting `exec startxfce4` into my user's `~/.xsession` I can launch default XFCE4 session when I connecect from my Windows via Remote Desktop and choose "Xorg" option on the login screen. But that's just default XFCE4, and I'd like to start Xubuntu session, with all its customizations to look and feel. Please advise how to achieve that.

Comment: Don't you have a Xubuntu xsession in `/usr/share/xsessions`? I'd assume it should work the same way as `xfce4session` mentioned above.

Comment: $ ls /usr/share/xsessions -la
total 36
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 16 18:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 317 root root 12288 Dec 17 09:35 ..
```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   303 Mar 26  2020 ubuntu.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  6273 Mar 30  2020 xfce.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  5962 Apr 20  2020 xubuntu.desktop```

Comment: That only some ".desktop" files. I mean how do I make it start by default instead of "plain" xfce session?

Comment: I've mistaken a bit in the question text. Actual content of the "~/.xsession" is "exec startxfce4"

Comment: Well, those "some .desktop files" is what you need. Look inside for what is executed in `xubuntu.desktop`. Also, do us all a favor, and don't post outputs as comments.

Comment: looked into that, but surprisingly both xfce.desktop and xubuntu.desktop just run "startxfce4", without any additional paramters there, i.e. what I already do. so what is the difference? so how do they produce different sessions?

Comment: mikewhatever, so your advise is unfortunately not helpful. I'm already doing that and have no desired effect.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is because several environment variables are not set and passed to startxfce4.  Create a /usr/local/bin/start-xubuntu file and put "start-xubuntu" in ~/.xsessions:

```
#!/bin/bash

export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/usr/share"
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg"

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export GDM_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export DESKTOP_SESSION=xubuntu
export GDMSESSION=xubuntu
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu

# propagate to X sessions. It is important when user first
# login, they decide on the initial xfce/xubuntu template settings.
dbus-update-activation-environment --verbose XDG_DATA_DIRS XDG_CONFIG_DIRS DESKTOP_SESSION GDMSESSION XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP

exec startxfce4
```

Kudos goes to [Netspectrum Ubuntu AMI on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B08BRR772D), which gives you a ready-to-go xubuntu desktop via VNC, RDP or browser in a few seconds.

Comment: A correction to the answer by @user4572254: put `start-xubuntu` in `~/.xsession` (not `~/.xsessions`.)

Comment: To reconnect correctly i made sure `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` had `test -x /tmp/.X11-unix/X10 || exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession` instead -- wherein X10 is the default xrdp display from the `X11DisplayOffset` from `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini` -- probably could do this better though